# Python - popping an element from a list

Tags: python, list

I am currently working in Python 3. I would like to make some modifications to a list. So, I copied the original `list(nums)` to another `list(nums1)`. When I am popping out any element from list nums1 then I am also loosing that element from nums. How do I make sure I am poppin an element only from one list.

```
nums = [1,2,3]
nums1 = nums
nums1.pop(1)
print(nums)
print(nums1)
```

output

```
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: `nums1 = nums` isn't doing what you think it's doing (probably). Check this out [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how to prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-to-prevent-it)

Comment: You are not really 'copying' the list. Use `nums.copy()` to do a real copying.

Comment: "So, I copied the original list(nums) to another list(nums1)." No you didn't, you didn't make a copy anywhere.  There is a single list in your code, being referenced by two different variables. You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with referencing `nums`.
To avoid this you can use `.copy()`.

```
nums = [1,2,3]
nums1 = nums.copy()
nums1.pop(1)
print(nums)
print(nums1)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
```